# Finding my old mass effect save files

Tags: steam, mass-effect-2, mass-effect

I recently went to continue an old game of Mass Effect 2 and was disappointed to find that all of my save files were missing.

That's Ok, I thought, I hadn't got that far in, I'll just restart the game with one of my Mass Effect 1 save files. That's when I found that they were missing too!

That's Ok, I thought, I'll recover them from backups. That's when I found that the directories where the Mass effect save files are now (`C:\Users\...\Documents\BioWare\Mass Effect 2`), were created when I recently opened the game, didn't exist before and thus there were no backups from that location!

So, how do I find my old Mass Effect save files? Did Steam once put ME1/2 save files in a different location? I.e has the location of save files changed? If so, where did they used to be?

Has anyone else experienced Mass Effect save files disappearing? If so, how did you recover your save files/where did you find them?

If it makes any difference, I think my upgrade to Windows 7 was after the last time I played either of these games, so I wonder if the OS change may have also affected the save game location.

As suggested, I installed MASGAU, sadly it only finds the current, empty save directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself managing save files often, you could give [MASGAU](http://masgau.org/downloads/) a try. It is a save-file manager that can scan your drive for saves, so you could use it to find your saves (if they are still existing).

**Always make backups!** *(BTW MASGAU's primary function is backup & restore of save files).*

Comment: The whole of my hard drive is continuously backed up, but as far as I can see, the save directories have never existed in that location before.

Comment: Often Steam game profiles are in a different folder than the standalone one. Have you scdanned for saves with masgau?

Comment: Yes @beppe9000 I asked MASGAU to search the whole of my machine, including all hard drives.

Comment: You could try to intall [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) and search manually for known file names.

Comment: I don't see how *Everything* could help, since I have no idea what the files were called, when they were deleted or what path they were deleted from. *Everything* can't search the CDP history database, for that I need to know which directory they were deleted from, hence my question.

Comment: go here to see save game path and file names: http://gamesave.info/MassEffect/ ie.You could search for the "BioGame.ini" file with everything and see if you get any results (to check if it has been moved).

Comment: I dont know what do you mean by CDP. Maybe you could try to run a recovery tool such as recuva pointing it to the "saves" subfolder but I think it may be too late for that. https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva

Comment: CDP is Continuous Data Protection, e.g. Apple Time Machine. My CDP backups go back over 10 years, so my ME2 save files must be in there somewhere, if I can work out where to look. The problem is, as I said in my question, the current save directory was created when I ran the game, it never existed before that, it doesn't exist in any older backups. So when I was running the game before, it must have been saving games to a different location - hence my question. Thanks for the `BioGame.ini` pointer though, old backups of that file might tell me where they used to be.

Comment: if you think out of the box you may find this website useful, tough: http://www.masseffectsaves.com/index.php